# For selected items from popup toggle div code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

My problem seems to be very complicated for me. So I need some help from you friends. I will try to explain it.

**Image1:**

[image]

In above image if user clicks on "+Add/Edit" then one popup like below image2 appears.

**Image2:**
[image]

If user selects any medical condition from popup it will get displayed on page like below image3

**Image3:**

[image]

The `HTML and script code` for above functionality is here(please ignore the result of fiddle, used for just code) :  https://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/cr6t1tds/

Now the one more new functionity I have to add.

**Image4:**

[image]

If we select any medical condition from **Image2** then "Family Medical History"
section as shown in **Image4** should appear. e.g. 'Alzheimer's Disease' and 'Asthma' are selected so when we click on popup button(Done) then "Family Medical History" section appears(this should toggle as per select/deselect) in which each has another '+Add/Edit'. On click of this '+Add/Edit' another popup will be opened as below **Image5**.

**Image5:** 
[image]

**Image5** popup will be same for "Family Medical History" section items but each can have different user inputs. After **Image5** popup user selection result should be like below Image

**Image6:**

[image]

**Question**: I am not getting how should I achieve this new functionality explained in Image4, Image5, and Image6.

Can anyone please help me in this? (Sorry for this long question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/z9qs3yp1/) you can find a [quick jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/z9qs3yp1/) in pure JQuery and HTML (no structures, no data persistence), the code is not so elegant (can be improved and simplified) but give you an idea about how you can get the desired behavior.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dlgMedical" style="display:none;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="None"> None</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="Depression"> Depression</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="Lung cancer"> Lung cancer</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="Anxiety"> Anxiety</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="Stroke"> Stroke</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
          <button class="btn btn-block btn-warning btn-lg" id="cmdDiseaseDone">
          DONE
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dlgParents" style="display:none;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="Mother"> Mother</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="Father"> Father</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="Brother"> Brother</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="Sister"> Sister</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="Uncle"> Uncle</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
          <button class="btn btn-block btn-warning btn-lg" id="cmdParentsDone">
          DONE
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel-title bold">FAMILY MEDICAL HISTORY CONDITION(S)</div>
      <h5>Select medical condition(s)</h5>
      <a id="addDisease">+ Add/Edit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">&nbsp;</div><div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel-title bold">FAMILY MEDICAL HISTORY</div>
      <h5>Select patient's family members</h5>
      <div id="divDisease"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.noTitleStuff .ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none;}
.bold{font-weight: bold;}
.item{font-style: italic;}
.addParent{padding:5px;}
```

**Javascript**

```
  $("#dlgMedical").dialog({autoOpen : false, modal : true, show : "blind", hide : "blind",dialogClass: 'noTitleStuff', width:400});

    $("#dlgParents").dialog({autoOpen : false, modal : true, show : "blind", hide : "blind",dialogClass: 'noTitleStuff', width:400});

  $( "#addDisease" ).click(function() {
    $("#dlgMedical").dialog( "open" );
  });
    $( "#cmdDiseaseDone" ).click(function() {
    // clear selection
    $('#divDisease').empty();
    // iterate selected disease
    $( "li > input:checked" ).each(function( index ) {
      // add history elements
      var newID = $( this ).attr('value').replace(' ','_');
      $('#divDisease').html($('#divDisease').html() + '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="item">'+$( this ).attr('value')+'</div></div></div><div id="div'+newID+'"></div><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><a id="'+newID+'" class="addParent">+ Add/Edit</a></div></div><div class="row">&nbsp;</div>'); 
      $( ".addParent" ).click(function(e) {
        selectedItem = $(e.target).attr('id');
        $("#dlgParents").dialog( "open" );
      });
    });
    // clear checked
    $( "li > input:checked" ).each(function( index ) {
      $( this ).prop('checked',false);
    });
    $("#dlgMedical").dialog( "close" );
  });

  var selectedItem;

    $( "#cmdParentsDone" ).click(function() {
    // clear selection
    var selectedDIV = $('#div'+selectedItem);
    selectedDIV.empty();
    // iterate selected disease
    selectedDIV.html('<ul>');
    $( "li > input:checked" ).each(function( index ) {
        selectedDIV.html(selectedDIV.html() + '<li class="item">'+$( this ).attr('value')+'</li>');
    });
    selectedDIV.html(selectedDIV.html() + '</ul>');
    // clear checked
    $( "li > input:checked" ).each(function( index ) {
      $( this ).prop('checked',false);
    });
    $("#dlgParents").dialog( "close" );
  });
```